# Asignment issue on nodejs

Tags: node.js, watson-conversation, watson

I am trying to replace some characters of a string according to the result of a ibm_db query, but I cannot seem to return the resultant string, here is the code:

EDIT: Here is the complete code

```
`function updateMessage(input, response) {
  var responseText = null;
  if (!response.output) {
   response.output = {};
  } else {
   // Regex to accept any format of phone numbers
   var regex = new RegExp( /3\d{2}(-| )?\d{3}(-| )?\d{4}/);
   if( response.context.service != "none" && regex.test( input.input.text )     ){
    var phoneNumber = [];
    for( var i = 0; i < response.entities.length; i++ ){
     if( response.entities[i].entity === 'sys-number' ){
      phoneNumber.push( response.entities[i].value );
     }
   }
  // Format the phone number, trim spaces and hypens if any
  phoneNumber = phoneNumber.join("");
  phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(/-/g, "");
  var query = "SELECT * FROM PLAN WHERE PHONENUMBER = ";
  query = query.concat( phoneNumber );
  conn.query( query, function( err, rows ){
   if( err ){
      console.log( "Error: ", err );
      return;
   }else{
      if( rows === "[]" ){
        answer = "NoData";
      }else{
        var output = response.output.text[0];
        response.output.text[0] = output.replace( 'cap', rows[0].CAPACITY );
        // return response;
      }
    }
 } );
   return response;
 }else{
   return response;
 }
}`
```

The response.output.text[0] is the String: "Your capacity is cap"
And it does not return the replaced string, can anyone enlight me about the correct approach for this? Thank you.

Comment: I tried the snippet and the return function seems to be working. Could you add the 'return response; ' inside the else and try.
conn.query( query, function( err, rows ){
 if( err ){
  console.log( "Error: ", err );
  return;
 }else{
  if( rows === "[]" ){
   answer = "NoData";
  }else{
   var output = response.output.text[0];
   response.output.text = output.replace( 'cap', rows[0].CAPACITY );
   return response;
  }
 }
} );

Comment: Could you add the full code snippet. I don't see why the replaced string is not returned.

Comment: If I do that I get the error on response.output.text[0] 
cannot read property '0' of null

Answer (score 0):

because of the asynchronous nature of nodejs it's obvious why you are facing this problem.
note that i/o bound operations are time consuming and it causes the system to be slow. in nodejs program whenever you call an i/o, it usually won't stay idle until getting the io result and it will try to execute the next lines of the code. you should return the response variable inside your db callback method.

```
conn.query( query, function( err, rows ){
    if( err ){
        console.log( "Error: ", err );
        return;
    }else{
        if( rows === "[]" ){
            answer = "NoData";
        }else{
            var output = response.output.text[0];
            response.output.text = output.replace( 'cap', rows[0].CAPACITY);
            return response;
        }
    }
});
```

for more information about the callbacks check this link:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_callbacks_concept.htm

Comment: Precisely same thing which i mentioned in my comment :)

Comment: thanks for your comment, I tried it but if I move the return statement inside the function I get the error on 
response.output.text[0] 
cannot read property '0' of null

Comment: Add another condition to see if response.output.text has a value or not